# HTC Sync fails to start when phone connected "updating htc library"

Tags: htc-sync-3.0, htc-desire-s

I have an HTC Desire S wich is failing to connect to HTC Sync. I have downloaded and installed the latest version but one of 2 possible scenarios occur:

1. The phone is connected to the pc. USB connection sound chimes and I see the phone in my Windows devices list. I then start HTC Sync. It will show the splash screen and use about 40-50% CPU power, but it will not go any farther... It only shows the message "Updating htc library".
2. The phone is not connected to USB. I start HTC Sync and wait for it to fully load. Then I connect the phone. Once again the phone shows up in my devices list, but HTC Sync will not recognize it, nor will it show my phone.

I am using Windows 7 x64, HTC Sync v3.0.5551 (june, 6th update by HTC).

Any help is greatly appreciated...

Comment: [This thread](http://www.htcforums.com/desire/6326-sync-issue-stuck-updating-htc-library.html) on the HTC forums makes it seem like it's something of a common issue with the 3.x releases, but I haven't the faintest idea of where to download the older 2.x versions. Google isn't turning up much that's, er...reputable.

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is due to errors related to HTC Sync, Windows 7 and Adobe AIR. There is a bug opened on Adobe site: https://bugbase.adobe.com/index.cfm?event=bug&id=2966976
The workaround should be to downgrade Adobe AIR to 2.6.xxx version. You can download it [here](http://filehippo.com/download_adobe_air/9669/). Upgrading to Adobe AIR 3.0.0.3880 RC1 didn't worked for me.